# How to pass blockNumber to viem call?

Tags: solidity, rpc, typescript, viem

I'm trying to view the owner of a certain NFT at a specific blockNumber, when I make the viem call without the `blockNumber` parameter it works perfectly, however, once I try to pass a `blockNumber` with the call, it errors out everytime.

Here is my code:

```js
import { createPublicClient, http } from "viem";
import { sepolia } from "viem/chains";

const client = createPublicClient({
  chain: sepolia,
  transport: http(),
});

const owner = await client.readContract({
    address: nftAddress,
    abi: nftAbi,
    functionName: "ownerOf",
    args: [tokenId],
    blockNumber: blockStart,
  });
```

I've tried casting `blockStart` using `BigInt()`, `Number()`, and `parseInt()`.

Here is the error:

```js
Error: ContractFunctionExecutionError: Missing or invalid parameters.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
Request body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","to":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f"},"0x415a8c"]}
 
Raw Call Arguments:
  to:    0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f
  data:  0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 
Contract Call:
  address:   0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f
  function:  ownerOf(uint256 tokenId)
  args:             (0)

Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/readContract.html
Details: missing trie node 0783b63a76a83968a7f0b86b6735d04130553a6e4b28d4ca6545c8edd7bec19a (path ) <nil>
Version: viem@1.18.7
    at getContractError (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/utils/errors/getContractError.js:26:12)
    at readContract (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/actions/public/readContract.js:57:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async getOwnerAtBlock (webpack-internal:///(api)/./utils/loyalty-harvest/createLeaves.ts:31:19)
    at async createLeaves (webpack-internal:///(api)/./utils/loyalty-harvest/createLeaves.ts:55:31)
    at async createLeavesAPI (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/createLeavesAPI.ts:25:39) {
  details: 'missing trie node 0783b63a76a83968a7f0b86b6735d04130553a6e4b28d4ca6545c8edd7bec19a (path ) <nil>',
  docsPath: '/docs/contract/readContract',
  metaMessages: [
    'URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org',
    'Request body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","to":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f"},"0x415a8c"]}',
    ' ',
    'Raw Call Arguments:',
    '  to:    0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f\n' +
      '  data:  0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    ' ',
    'Contract Call:',
    '  address:   0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f\n' +
      '  function:  ownerOf(uint256 tokenId)\n' +
      '  args:             (0)'
  ],
  shortMessage: 'Missing or invalid parameters.\n' +
    'Double check you have provided the correct parameters.',
  version: 'viem@1.18.7',
  cause: CallExecutionError: Missing or invalid parameters.
  Double check you have provided the correct parameters.
```

Does this have anything to do with the public Sepolia RPC URL not being able to read data from old blocks or am I passing it incorrectly? [Here](https://viem.sh/docs/contract/readContract.html#blocknumber-optional) is the `blockNumer` section of `readContract` from the viem docs.

Here is another code snippet where I try to view `Transfer` events in the contract, it errors out when I pass `fromBlock` and `toBlock`:

```js
const events = await client.getContractEvents({
    address: nftAddress,
    abi: nftAbi,
    eventName: "Transfer",
    fromBlock: blockStart,
    toBlock: blockEnd,
  });
```

The error for this snippet:

```js
Error: InvalidParamsRpcError: Invalid parameters were provided to the RPC method.
Double check you have provided the correct parameters.

URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
Request body: {"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],"fromBlock":"4283020","toBlock":"4283030"}]}

Details: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix
Version: viem@1.18.7
    at withRetry.delay.count.count (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/utils/buildRequest.js:42:27)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async attemptRetry (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/utils/promise/withRetry.js:12:30) {
  details: 'invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix',
  docsPath: undefined,
  metaMessages: [
    'URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org',
    'Request body: {"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],"fromBlock":"4283020","toBlock":"4283030"}]}'
  ],
  shortMessage: 'Invalid parameters were provided to the RPC method.\n' +
    'Double check you have provided the correct parameters.',
  version: 'viem@1.18.7',
  cause: RpcRequestError: RPC Request failed.
  
  URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org
  Request body: {"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],"fromBlock":"4283020","toBlock":"4283030"}]}
  
  Details: invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix
  Version: viem@1.18.7
      at request (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/clients/transports/http.js:43:27)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async withRetry.delay.count.count (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/utils/buildRequest.js:26:20)
      at async attemptRetry (file:///home/trauki/practice/ScaffoldLoyaltyHarvest/packages/nextjs/node_modules/viem/_esm/utils/promise/withRetry.js:12:30) {
    details: 'invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix',
    docsPath: undefined,
    metaMessages: [
      'URL: https://rpc.sepolia.org',
      'Request body: {"method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address":"0x52469E13ac6DdbFbf803F48E7106f8294E2B888f","topics":["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"],"fromBlock":"4283020","toBlock":"4283030"}]}'
    ],
    shortMessage: 'RPC Request failed.',
    version: 'viem@1.18.7',
    cause: {
      code: -32602,
      message: 'invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix'
    },
    code: -32602
  },
  code: -32602
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

You are on the right track. The `missing trie node` error you are getting means that you are trying to request the state from blocks that have been pruned; in simpler terms, this means that you need to query an archive node while the public endpoint Viem is using by default is probably a full node; this means only the states of the past 128 blocks can be accessed.

Here is how you can add your own endpoint using the `createPublicClient` method. Here is an example to retreive the balance of an address.

```js
import { createPublicClient, http } from "viem";
import { toHex } from "viem";

// Define an async function
async function getBalance() {

  const transport = http(
    "YOUR_ARCHIVE_NODE"
  );

  const client = createPublicClient({
    transport,
  });

  try {
    const blockNumber = 4283020;

    // Await the promise from getBalance and store the result
    const balance = await client.getBalance({
      address: "0x8f8e7012F8F974707A8F11C7cfFC5d45EfF5c2Ae",
      blockTag: toHex(blockNumber),
    });

    // Process the balance as needed
    console.log(balance);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occur during the API call
    console.error("Error fetching balance:", error);
  }
}

// Call the async function
getBalance();
```

If you are getting an error about `invalid argument 0: hex string without 0x prefix`, means that you have to convert the decimal value of the block number to hex.

You can do it usign the [`toHex` function](https://viem.sh/docs/utilities/toHex.html):

```js
import { toHex } from "viem";

const hexValue = toHex(4283020);

console.log(hexValue);
```

So your code will be like this:

```js
import { toHex } from "viem";

const events = await client.getContractEvents({
    address: nftAddress,
    abi: nftAbi,
    eventName: "Transfer",
    fromBlock: toHex(blockStart),
    toBlock: toHex(blockEnd),
  });
```

Using an archive node plus converting the decimal values to Hex will solve those issues!

> You can learn more about the difference between full and archive nodes in this article: [EVM nodes: A dive into the full nodes vs. archive nodes](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/)
>
> Full disclosure, I wrote the article.

Feel free to reach out if you have more questions!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is because you didn't initialize your public client with a transport url. The [viem http transport documentation](https://viem.sh/docs/clients/transports/http.html#usage) states:

> If no url is provided, then the transport will fall back to a public RPC URL on the chain. It is highly recommended to provide an authenticated RPC URL to prevent rate-limiting.

Since you aren't providing a transport url it is using the default public one for Sepolia. If you use one from an RPC provider such as Alchemy, you won't encounter these issues.

Revised client:

```js
const client = createPublicClient({
  chain: sepolia,
  transport: http("https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/<YOUR_KEY>"),
});
```